# Is volatile needed with indirect access?

Tags: c#, multithreading, volatile

*Please note I am not asking about replacing `volatile` with other means (like lock), I am asking about `volatile` nature -- thus I use "needed" in sense, `volatile` or no `volatile`.*

Consider such case that one thread only write to variable `x` (`Int32`) and the other thread only reads it. The access in both cases is direct.

The `volatile` is needed to avoid caching, correct?

But what if the access to `x` is indirect -- for example via property:

```
int x;
int access_x { get { return x; } set { x = value; } }
```

So both threads now uses only `access_x`, not `x`. Is `x` needed to be marked as `volatile`? If yes is there some limit of indirection when `volatile` is not needed anymore?

*Update*: consider such code of the reader (no writes):

```
if (x>10)
   ...
// second thread changes `x`
if (x>10)
  ...
```

In the second `if` compiler **could** evaluate use the old value because `x` could be in cache and without `volatile` there is no need to refetch. My question is about such change:

```
if (access_x>10)
   ...   
// second thread changes `x`
if (access_x>10)
  ...
```

And let's say I skip `volatile` for `x`. What will happen / what can happen?

Comment: You generally do not want to use volatile to start with. Property does not change anything in this case.

Comment: Adding a property doesn't make the read/write 'indirect'. It just changes the part of code concerned with `x`. In other words, if you were going to receive a stale value of `x` *without* a property, the code in the property getter would also receive a stale value of `x`.

Comment: @Rob, thank you, but I don't understand your first sentence. Say I write `x = 7`. This is direct assignment. When I call `setFoo()` and it calls `setBar()` and it calls `setMe()` and it calls `setX()` and it calls property setter I will say there is a lot of indirections. So why you don't count property as indirection, after all those are methods in disguise?

Comment: @astrowalker It's many levels of indirection, only if you're viewing it from `setFoo`s point of view. From `setX`'s point of view, there's no indirection. `setX` directly modifies `x`. There's no reason to say `setFoo` is more important than `setX`

Comment: @Rob, I am viewing it from the level of setFoo because at this level I "consume" data, and since I am calling a method/function I wonder what is done to cache in C#/.Net world. After all it could be a thousand of methods in the chain so it is hard to believe entire code sits in cache with all the data as well and those indirections does not influence the it. See the update.

Comment: That getter could get inlined into the callers, and end up referencing `x` "directly". Since you seem to care about lock-free designs, you should really have a look at the Linux kernel's documentation, and see the kinds of things that can go wrong. http://events.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/dbueso-elc2016-membarriers-final.pdf

Comment: @JonathonReinhart, thank you very much! Could you post your comment as regular answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is `x` needed to be marked as `volatile`?

Yes, and no (but mostly yes).

"Yes", because technically you have no guarantees here. The compilers (C# and JIT) are permitted to make *any* optimization they see fit, as long as the optimization would not change the behavior of the code when executed in a single-thread. One obvious optimization is to omit the call to the property setter and getter and just directly access the field (i.e. inlining). Of course, the compiler is allowed to do whatever analysis it wants and make further optimizations.

"No", because in practice this usually is not a problem. With the access wrapped in a method, the C# compiler won't optimize away the field, and the JIT compiler is *unlikely* to do so (even if the methods are inlined…again, no guarantees, but AFAIK such an optimization isn't performed, and I think it not likely a future version would). So all you're left with is memory coherency issues (the other reason `volatile` is used…i.e. essentially dealing with optimizations performed at the hardware level).

As long as your code is only ever going to run on Intel x86-compatible hardware, that hardware treats all reads and writes as volatile.

However, other platforms may be different. Itanium and ARM being a couple of common examples which have different memory models.

Personally, I prefer to write to the technicalities. Writing code that just happens to work, in spite of a lack of guarantee, is just asking to find some time in the future that the code stops working for some mysterious reason.

So IMHO you really should mark the field as `volatile`.

> If yes is there some limit of indirection when volatile is not needed anymore?

No. If such a limit existed, it would have to be documented to be useful. In practice, the limit in terms of compiler optimizations is really just a "level of indirection" (as you put it). But no amount of levels of indirection avoid the hardware-level optimizations, and even the limit in terms of compiler optimizations is strictly "in practice". You have no guarantee that the compiler will never analyze the code more deeply and perform more aggressive optimizations, to any arbitrarily deep level of calls.

More generally, my rule of thumb is this: if I am trying to decide whether I should use some particular feature that I know is normally used to protect against bugs in concurrency-related scenarios, and I have to ask "do I really need this feature, or will the code work fine without it?", then I probably don't know enough about the way that feature works for me to safely avoid using it.

Consider it a variation on the old "if you have to ask how much it costs, you can't afford it."

Comment: Thank you, for the record I was not looking for some dirty trick to make, I wanted to have better understanding. And I am in camp "safety first" :-).